# Editorfor checkbox field onclick

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I have an editorfor field that is a checkbox and when it is changed from false to true and the form is submitted i need to track that the checkbox was changed and is marked true. Also it has to be a javascript or jquery function.

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsPublic)

</div>
```

If i need to explain this better please tell me. I just cant think of how else to explain.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope following code will do it:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsPublicChanged) @*create special model field for handling change event*@

$().ready(function () {
            //catch change event and assign value to hidden field
    $("input[name=IsPublic]").on("change", function () {
        $("input[name=IsPublicChanged]").val('true');
    });
});
```

Or some different js-code if you want to see if value of checkbox was changed comparing to it's initial value:

```
$().ready(function () {
    var trackValue = $("input[name=IsPublic]").prop("checked");

    $("form").on("submit", function () {
        var actualValue = $("input[name=IsPublic]").prop("checked");
        if (actualValue != trackValue) {
            $("input[name=IsPublicChanged]").val('true');
        }
    });     
});
```